# No suitable constructor found for ChatMessage(String,String)

Tags: java, android, firebase, constructor

```
Error:(88, 79) error: no suitable constructor found for ChatMessage(String,String)
    constructor ChatMessage.ChatMessage(String,String,long) is not applicable
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor ChatMessage.ChatMessage() is not applicable
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

This is my code for the related error:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(), FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()));
```

And ChatMessage constructor that the error relates to:

```
public ChatMessage(String messageText, String messageUser, long messageTime) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
        this.messageUser = messageUser;

        messageTime = new Date().getTime();
    }
```

I followed a YouTube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xn0tQHpMDnM and a number of comments mentioned the same error, but no one received a response.

Comment: you forgot the last parameter (`long messageTime`) add that and the call will work

Comment: And if you would read the error message yourself, you would see that there is all given to solve your problem

Comment: Remove long messageTime from the constructor parameter. You are not using it.

Comment: @RamKumar i would guess it's not in his power to change the constructor, e.g. an external library

Comment: @Lino No need to guess. Watch the video

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the constructor of `ChatMessage` class using three arguments:

```
ChatMessage(String messageText, String messageUser, long messageTime)
```

To create a new object of `ChatMessage` class, you need to pass not only two arguments as i see in you code, but three. So in order to solve your problem, please use the following line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
     .push()
     .setValue(new ChatMessage(
          input.getText().toString(),
          FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),
          null));
```

As you probably see, i have added as the last argument `null` because you are creating a new instance of Date inside your `ChatMessage` class.

Comment: No. That third parameter should be removed from the constructor. The default time is `new Date().getTime()`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't follow the video correctly or you didn't bother to check the description to [see the source code](https://github.com/eddydn/ChatApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/dev/edmt/chatapp/ChatMessage.java#L9-L18).

Remove the third parameter.

```
public class ChatMessage {
    private String messageText;
    private String messageUser;
    private long messageTime;

    public ChatMessage(String messageText, String messageUser) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
        this.messageUser = messageUser;


        messageTime = new Date().getTime();
```

The default message time is 'now', in seconds since epoch

> number of comments have mentioned the same error

I see different errors mentioned that relate to using `getValue(ChatMessage.value)` incorrectly, not the error you have

If you wanted to have 3 parameters, you'd want this **in addition** to the previous.

```
public ChatMessage(String messageText, String messageUser, long messageTime) {
    this.messageText = messageText;
    this.messageUser = messageUser;

    this.messageTime = messageTime
}
```